# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError on JSoup.connect( String url ).get

Tags: android, jsoup, air-native-extension

I'm having a weird problem with JSoup in an Android AIR Native Extension.

I'm trying to load a page from YouTube to extract some data from the comments.

Here is the "offending" code:

```
private class ConnectToYouTube {
    public String html = null;
    public Exception error = null;
}

private class ConnectToYouTubeTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ConnectToYouTubeResult>
{
    @Override 
    protected ConnectToYouTubeResult doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        ConnectToYouTubeResult result = new ConnectToYouTubeResult();

        String videoId = params[0];

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+videoId).get(); // in the catlog this is line 138
            Elements foo = doc.select("#comment-text");
            result.html  = foo.html();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            result.error = e;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is the adb catlog

```
E/AndroidRuntime(12131): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
E/AndroidRuntime(12131): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at org.jsoup.nodes.Document$OutputSettings.<init>(Document.java:210)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at org.jsoup.nodes.Document.<init>(Document.java:18)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.initialiseParse(TreeBuilder.java:27)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:40)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.parse(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:37)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parseInput(Parser.java:30)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:481)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at com.freshplanet.ane.AirYouTube.extractor.YouTubeExtractor$ConnectToYouTubeTask.doInBackground(YouTubeExtractor.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at com.freshplanet.ane.AirYouTube.extractor.YouTubeExtractor$ConnectToYouTubeTask.doInBackground(YouTubeExtractor.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    ... 4 more
E/AndroidRuntime(12131): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode.<clinit>(Entities.java:20)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    ... 17 more
E/AndroidRuntime(12131): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: in == null
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:246)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.loadEntities(Entities.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.<clinit>(Entities.java:121)
E/AndroidRuntime(12131):    ... 18 more
```

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the Jsoup library is in the Libs folder. I spend a good 2 hours banging my head against this error when that was the problem. Hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

yes @user1814155 is right, I spend 2 days for this:D

```
Make sure the Jsoup library is in the Libs folder. I spend a good 2 hours banging my head against this error when that was the problem. Hope this helps, cheers. – user1814155
```